# Func<T,TResult> is not a Func<T,TResult>

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

I try to compare two type definitions. One definition is `Func<,>`. The other is generic definition of `Func<T,TResults>` which, I think, should be `Func<,>` as well.

The comparison returns false:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    public class Program
    {
        static Func<T, TResult> get_f2<T, TResult>()
        {
            return input => default(TResult);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<int, int> f1 = x => 2 * x;
            Type f1_def = f1.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition();

            MethodInfo f2_maker = typeof(Program).GetMethod("get_f2", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
            Type f2_def = f2_maker.ReturnType;

            Console.WriteLine(f1_def.ToString() + " " + f2_def.ToString() + " " + (f1_def == f2_def).ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled it with .net 4.5.

The result is

```
System.Func`2[T,TResult] System.Func`2[T,TResult] False
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `f1_def` prints as `` System.Func`2[T,TResult] `` because it's the generic type definition, that's just how `Func<,>` names its type arguments.

Your `f2_def` prints as `` System.Func`2[T,TResult] `` because it's not the generic type definition `Func<,>`, but it's actually put in the generic type arguments of your *method*. Things get confusing because `Func<,>`'s generic type arguments have the same name as your method's generic type arguments.

You should be able to more clearly see the difference by changing your method's generic type argument names to `A` and `B`.

Comment: Missed the `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` call.

Comment: But how can it be put in the generic type arguments of mymethod, if I haven't invoked the method with any generic arguments? I cannot retreive definition from `f2_def`, (`GetGenericTypeDefinition()` call throws exception) which suggests, that it's already a definition. Am I wrong? By now, the solution, proposed by @Hans Passant works.

Comment: @user2136963 No, `Type f2_def = f2_maker.ReturnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();` works just fine, it doesn't throw any exception, and after that, `f1_def` and `f2_def` compare equal.

Comment: I wote it again and got no exceptions. My fault. Thanks!